# How do I stop posts from friends of friends on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How do I stop receiving posts in the newsfeed on Facebook when one of my friends likes or comments on a photo of somebody who is not one of my friends?  I really don't want my newsfeed filled with pictures of somebody that I am not friends with.

Answer (score -1):

got to the profile of the person and click unfollow

Comment: This would mean unsubscribing from all posts from that user, not just comments/likes on friend's friends. Which is not what the asker wants.